# How to remove the old sprites in pygame and show them at a different location

Tags: sprites, pygame

I am trying to show the motion of some basketballs towards walle using the pygae sprites. The idea is that I don't know how to remove the old ones so they won't show. Is there a move method so that it would know it has to draw it again at the specified location? 
I created a sprite class. Then I have a Character class that uses the sprite class and threads to calculate the intermediary coordinates for them. But I don't want them to show on the screen forever, like the pictures show.
Thanks!

```
 import pygame

 class CharacterSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

   def __init__(self, location, image, surface):
       pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
       self.image = pygame.image.load(image).convert_alpha()
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
       self.rect.center = location
       self.surface = surface

    def draw(self):
       self.surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

   def update(self, location):
      self.rect.center = location
      self.draw()


import threading
import pygame
import os
from random import randint
from Sprites.CharacterSprite import CharacterSprite

LOCK = threading.Lock()


class StudentCharacter(threading.Thread):
   NRSTEPS = 3
   YPOS = 440
   TEACHERPOS = 40
   IMAGE_PATH = os.path.join('images', 'ball.png')

def __init__(self, screen, xpos, interval):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.screen, self.xpos, self.ypos, self.interval = screen, xpos, self.YPOS, interval
    self.draw(self.xpos, self.ypos)
    self.configure()


def draw(self, x, y):
    self.circle = CharacterSprite([x, y], self.IMAGE_PATH, self.screen)
    self.circle.draw()


def configure(self):
    (left, right) = self.interval
    self.target = randint(left, right)
    xdif = self.target - self.xpos
    ydif = self.TEACHERPOS - self.ypos
    self.normal = {'x': int(xdif / self.NRSTEPS), 'y': int(ydif / self.NRSTEPS)}
    print self.target, self.normal['x'], self.normal['y']


def update(self):
    self.circle.update([self.xpos, self.ypos])

def run(self):
    i = 0
    while i < self.NRSTEPS:
        LOCK.acquire()
        pygame.time.wait(100)
        self.xpos += self.normal['x']
        self.ypos += self.normal['y']
        self.update()
        print self.xpos, self.ypos
        pygame.display.update()
        i += 1
        LOCK.release()
    print "Done"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to redraw the background each frame, otherwise everything that you have drawn on the screen stays there.

Comment: So there's no easier and elegant way? This is so annoying ... I heard about this but thought that the update method will do this for me somehow ... Is there a way let's say to redraw only the old basketball with the background color and not the whole background?

Comment: Yes, thats called dirty blitting and Newbie Guide to pygame touches on this. The steps they say to follow to implement it are:
Blit a piece of the background over the sprite’s current location, erasing it.
Append the sprite’s current location rectangle to a list called dirty_rects.
Move the sprite.
Draw the sprite at it’s new location.
Append the sprite’s new location to my dirty_rects list.
Call display.update(dirty_rects)

You can read more about it here: http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Maybe you could write it as an answer so that I could mark it as correct...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, thats called *dirty blitting*. The *Newbie Guide to pygame* [touches on this](http://pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html).

The steps they recommend to implement it are:

1. Blit a piece of the background over the sprite’s current location, erasing it.
2. Append the sprite’s current location rectangle to a list called `dirty_rects`.
3. Move the sprite. Draw the sprite at it’s new location.
4. Append the sprite’s new location to my `dirty_rects` list. Call `display.update(dirty_rects)`